# Ricoh MPC3300 printing sheet per sheet on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: printing, ricoh

I have installed the Ricoh MPC3300 printer on my laptop.
I used the **choose from Database** option and chose for the MPC 3300.

The drivers works but is very slow. It seems to be printing a sheet then waiting a while before printing a sheet again...

Answer (score 1):

Installed new drivers (PPD) from :
http://www.openprinting.org/download/PPD/Ricoh/PXL/

Used the PXL.
Ricoh Aficio MP C3300 PXL

Go to **Printers** - right mouse click - **properties** - **Make and Model** - Select the downloaded ppd